# RuntimeError: CuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS

Tags: pytorch, cudnn

I am running code that UI downloaded from github. It is supposed to be working (I saw that other people managed to activate it). When I try to run it I get the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: CuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS
```

The code uses pytorch 0.4.1. I have cuda installed.

When I run the command `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt`
I get the answer:

```
CUDA Version 10.0.130
```

When I run the command `conda list -n <my env name>`
I see:

```
cudatoolkit ver 9.0
cudnn       ver 7.6.5
```

And now, my question:

What should I do to avoid this error?
Do I need to use `pip install` for a more recent version of cudnn? If so, which one?

Comment: What kind of GPU device are you using?

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same issue. In my case, the PyTorch version was 0.4.1, and the Cuda version was 9.0. I solved the issue by adding this piece of code:

```
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    print("working on gpu")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    print("working on cpu")
```